# How can I solve the following problem using the complementary slackness property?

Tags: matrices, optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems, discrete-optimization

Prove that for every matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ exactly one of the following statements is true:

1. $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Ax > 0$
2. $\exists y \in \mathbb{R}^m : A^T y = 0 \wedge y \geq 0 \wedge y \neq 0$

I tried writing a linear program and its dual and then I tried to use the [b][u]complementary slackness property[/u][/b].

I wrote the linear program as:
max $0^Tx$
$Ax \geq 0 $
$x \geq 0 $

Should I have defined a different linear program? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the dual of the LP that you've written down?  How does it relate to statement 2?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need complementary slackness, Farkas' Lemma for a system of linear inequalities does all the work.

Farkas' Lemma: For $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$, the system $Ax \le b$ has a solution if and only if there is no vector $u \in \mathbb{R}^m$ with $u \ge 0$, $u^tA = 0^t$ and $u^tb < 0$.

Now  statement 2. is equivalent to: $\exists \varepsilon > 0$ (where $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^m$) such that the system $A^Ty = 0, y\ge \varepsilon$ has a solution.

We can rewrite this as: $\exists \varepsilon>0$ s.t. the system $\begin{pmatrix}
A^t\\-A^t\\-Id
\end{pmatrix}y \le \begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\-\varepsilon
\end{pmatrix}$ has a solution.

By Farkas' Lemma, this is equivalent to: $\exists \varepsilon > 0$ s.t. the system $u\ge 0, u^t\begin{pmatrix}
A^t\\-A^t \\-Id
\end{pmatrix}^t= 0, u^t\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\-\varepsilon
\end{pmatrix}<0$ does not have a solution, which is equivalent to:

$\exists \varepsilon > 0$ s.t. $\not \exists u_1,u_2,u_3 \ge 0: Au_1-Au_2-u_3 = 0, u_3^t\varepsilon \neq 0$.

This is equivalent to:
$\not \exists u_1,u_2,u_3 \ge 0: A(u_1-u_2) = u_3, u_3 \neq 0$, which is equivalent to:

$\not \exists x: Ax \neq 0 \iff \not \exists x: Ax > 0$.

This completes the proof.